# how do you cast from a const string namespace

Tags: php, casting, constants, abstract

Im trying to figure out a way to easily cast a dynamically created object so i can see its properties and exposed methods in my IDE. It seems to be acting weird when the string includes a fully qualified namespace.

Is there anyway I can cast objects from a const string in an abstract class ??

```
abstract class Models
{
    const MODEL = "foo\\bar\\Model";
}


//OK
    $p1 = "foo\\bar\\Model";
    $p2 = new $p1; 

//FAILS

    //$wannaDoThis = (Models::MODEL) Generator::generate(Models::MODEL);


    //$str1 = Models::MODEL;
    //$str2 = (string) Models::MODEL;
    //$o1 = new Models::MODEL;
    //$o2 = new "".Models::MODEL;
    //$o3 = new (Models::MODEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php

namespace foo\bar;

class Model
{
}

namespace SomeOtherNamespace;

abstract class Models
{
    const MODEL = "foo\\bar\\Model";
}

$class = Models::MODEL;
$x = new $class();
var_dump($x);
```

Which you can see here https://3v4l.org/87sKs

Comment: Im aware of this, but I'm not looking to instantiate the class, I'm looking to cast an instance like this :

$wannaDoThis = (Models::MODEL) Generator::generate(Models::MODEL);

Comment: Then this should work. `$wannaDoThis = Generator::generate(Models::MODEL);` The cast at the front you typed doesn't exist, that's more like Java!

Comment: That works perfectly, but doesn't help me ... it was so my IDE could expose functions and properties on my dynamically created models, but I guess it's not possible :(

Comment: Sorry, amigo,  that isn't possible